# How to apply filters to existing mails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I created a filter in Gmail, but forgot to apply it to already existing messages. Is there any way to apply filters to existing messages?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Also apply filter to xx matching conversations.` option is available next to search filter in gmail

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that. But if the filter already exists, how do I apply it?

Comment: Go to settings , filters tab... Click edit... use the same settings ( change if required ) and click continue... In this step you can update the filter by checking also apply filter for existing matching conversations ...

Comment: Can I do this in inbox.google.com?

Comment: I don't see this option ... :( is it no longer there?

Comment: @tsar2512 the option is still there, but it apparently has moved next to the other checkboxes, just below "Never mark it as important" and "Categorize as..."

Comment: asvignesh said this before, but it might be worth repeating, that option is on the page after selecting "Continue".

Comment: Holy moly! Thanks @asvignesh! This must be the most brain-dead UI choice I've ever seen!

Comment: I had to switch the Gmail interface to the English language, because the Czech translation sounded really, well, at least unintuitively, but I have found out, it well matches the original text. So "_Also apply filter to matching conversations_" actually means to apply the filter to already received messages? I thought it means something like: apply the filter to replies (i.e. the conversations) of messages matching the filter - so even if a message doesn't match the filter, if it's a reply to a message matching the filter, the filter will be also applied to such message.

Comment: In 2021 gmail doesn't appear to be able to apply this to existing emails. I have 43k emails in Promotions, and selecting `Also apply filter to matching conversations.` does not apply the filter of `category:promotions` to existing emails in the Promotions category. The search for `category:promotions` finds all the emails just fine, but I can't apply `Skip the Inbox (Archive it)` to them.

Comment: @J-mster Hm, but now it doesn't show the number.